# Where is Laravel's custom request return array

Tags: laravel

If I use `validate` in `Controller` like this `$validatedAttributes = $request->validate([...]);` I have the plain array in my `$validatedAttributes` variable.

If I'm using a class `class StoreInternalInvoiceRequest extends FormRequest` and accepting its instance in controller `public function store(StoreInternalInvoiceRequest $r)`

how do I access said array? I know it must be something simple, but I can't find it in the documentation. Also doing `$r->all()` is not it, because there still is the `csrf token`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Store a new blog post.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StorePostRequest  $request
 * @return Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
{
    // The incoming request is valid...

    // Retrieve the validated input data...
    $validated = $request->validated();

    // Retrieve a portion of the validated input data...
    $validated = $request->safe()->only(['name', 'email']);
    $validated = $request->safe()->except(['name', 'email']);
}
```